# Parallelised collections in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

What's the concept of "Paralleled collections" in Spark is, and how this concept can improve the overall performance of a job? Besides, how should partitions be configured for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel collections are provided in the Scala language as a simple way to parallelize data processing in Scala. The basic idea is that when you perform operations like `map`, `filter`, etc... to a collection it is possible to parallelize it using a thread pool. This type of parallelization is called data parallelization because it is based on the data itself. This is happening locally in the JVM and Scala will use as many threads as cores are available to the JVM.

On the other hand Spark is based on RDD, that are an abstraction that represents a distributed dataset. Unlike the Scala parallel collections this datasets are distributed in several nodes. Spark is also based on data parallelism, but this time is distributed data parallelism. This allows you to parallelize much more than in a single JVM, but it also introduces other issues related with data shuffling.

In summary, Spark implements a distributed data parallelism system, so everytime you execute a `map`, `filter`, etc... you are doing something similar to what a Scala parallel collection would do but in a distributed fashion. Also the unit of parallelism in Spark are partitions, while in Scala collections is each row.

You could always use Scala parallel collections inside a Spark task to parallelize within a Spark task, but you won't necessarily see performance improvement, specially if your data was already evenly distributed in your RDD and each task needs about the same computational resources to be executed.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin what's your opinion ?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you are right, I was generalizing too much, I have edited to be more precise about what I was trying to say

Comment: Make sure use parallelize() method only when the index of elements does not matter, because once parallelized to partitions, any transformation are done parallelly on partitions.